# Geohash Oracle implementation

Tags: oracle, geohashing

I found lots of implementations of Geohash, for lots of technologies. But I wasn't be able to find anyone for Oracle.

Does anyone know how to use Geohash in Oracle? Is there any Geohash implementation?
I would need a encoder and decoder, but the encoder is most important for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have the lat,lon data of the objects, then I would take an implementation in Java like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/geospatialweb/source/browse/trunk/geohash/src/Geohash.java) and [create a java class](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5012.htm) (>= version 10g).

Also have a look on the [wiki entry about geohashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) in case you want to use the hash for proximity searches.

Comment: Thank you kiwiwings. My question was related exclussively to Oracle. I'd want to encode and decode geohashes directly from Oracle database, using the lat,lon already stored in the db.

Comment: Apart from the wiki link, the answer was exclusively for oracle. You know, that similar to plsql, you can create a java class in the schema, which can be called either from plsql or also as a function from sql. Regarding the processing speed, you'll need to test it, if it's sufficent for your amount of data.